# Docker pip install -r requirements.txt raise an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/conda-bld/cffi_1642701102775/work'

Tags: python, docker

I build my own image on other's image. Requirements.txt just cannot be installed in my image. The pip command can run in container but not in build dockerfile.

```
Dockerfile:
    RUN /usr/local/python/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    COPY requirements.txt /data/requirements.txt
    RUN pip3 install -r /data/requirements.txt

Error:
    Step 4/4 : RUN pip3 install -r /data/requirements.txt
     ---> Running in 8f2818b35b3b
    Processing /opt/conda/conda-bld/cffi_1642701102775/work
    ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/conda-bld/cffi_1642701102775/work'
```

Comment: did you try `sudo` or `pip install -r /data/requirements.txt --user`